# Python Pandas dataframe - for each item in one column, find related items in another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am very new to Python so forgive me if my question sounds simple. I have data within a dataframe which I need to produce a new dataframe from.

| New ID | Prev ID | YEAR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID5 | ID4 | 2022 |
| ID4 | ID3 | 2021 |
| ID3 | ID2 | 2020 |
| ID2 | ID1 | 2019 |
| ID1 | ID2 | 2018 |
| AB2 | AB1 | 2022 |
| AB1 | NULL | 2021 |

What I would like to do is take the first ID (ID5) from "New ID" and then look in "Prev ID" to then find that in "New ID" and then repeat until I have found all related items. I'd then get the next ID (ID4) and repeat the above all the way down the columns so I would end up with this:

| Selected ID | Related ID | YEAR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID5 | ID5 | 2022 |
| ID5 | ID4 | 2022 |
| ID5 | ID3 | 2022 |
| ID5 | ID2 | 2022 |
| ID5 | ID1 | 2022 |
| ID4 | ID4 | 2021 |
| ID4 | ID3 | 2021 |
| ID4 | ID2 | 2021 |
| ID4 | ID1 | 2021 |
| ID3 | ID3 | 2020 |
| ID3 | ID2 | 2020 |
| ID3 | ID1 | 2020 |
| ID2 | ID2 | 2019 |
| ID2 | ID1 | 2019 |
| ID1 | ID1 | 2018 |
| AB2 | AB2 | 2022 |
| AB2 | AB1 | 2022 |
| AB1 | AB1 | 2021 |

I can do this in SQL by looping through a table but it is very slow with the amount of data I am using. I was hoping Python could speed this up?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you just want to sort the columns?

Comment: I posted an answer. You can let me know if there was a problem.

Comment: No it is not a case of sorting the columns unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

This does it:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
csv = StringIO("""New ID  Prev ID  YEAR
ID5  ID4  2022
ID4  ID3  2021
ID3  ID2  2020
ID2  ID1  2019
ID1  ID2  2018
AB2  AB1  2022
AB1  NULL  2021 """)

df = pd.read_csv(csv, sep='\s\s+')
df


 New ID Prev ID YEAR
0    ID5    ID4 2022
1    ID4    ID3 2021
2    ID3    ID2 2020
3    ID2    ID1 2019
4    ID1    ID2 2018
5    AB2    AB1 2022
6    AB1    NaN 2021
```

---

```
import re
from string import digits
def get_digit(string):
    return re.findall("\d+", string)

selected_id = pd.concat([pd.Series(df['New ID'][df['New ID']==i].repeat(get_digit(i))) for i in df['New ID'].to_list()]).to_frame()
related_id = selected_id['New ID'].astype(str).str.slice(0,2) + selected_id.groupby('New ID').cumcount(ascending=False).add(1).astype(str)
new_df = pd.concat([selected_id, related_id], axis=1).rename(columns={'New ID': 'Selected ID', 0:'Related ID'}).reset_index(drop=True)
new_df.merge(df, left_on='Selected ID', right_on='New ID', how='left').drop(['New ID', 'Prev ID'], axis=1)

Selected ID Related ID  YEAR
0    ID5    ID5 2022
1    ID5    ID4 2022
2    ID5    ID3 2022
3    ID5    ID2 2022
4    ID5    ID1 2022
5    ID4    ID4 2021
6    ID4    ID3 2021
7    ID4    ID2 2021
8    ID4    ID1 2021
9    ID3    ID3 2020
10   ID3    ID2 2020
11   ID3    ID1 2020
12   ID2    ID2 2019
13   ID2    ID1 2019
14   ID1    ID1 2018
15   AB2    AB2 2022
16   AB2    AB1 2022
17   AB1    AB1 2021
```

Comment: Glad it helped. You can also accept and upvote answers if you find them helpful. Good luck!

Comment: Hello again. Do you have a method of doing this where the IDs would be in this sort of format:

New ID = aaaaaa/01/2013/0000 (the year is 2013)
Prev ID = aaaaaa/01/2012/0000 (the year is 2012)

New ID = 22bbbbbbbbbb (22 is the year 2022)
Prev ID = 21bbbbbbbbbb (21 is the year 2021)